# Titanium Appcelerator drawing on the map using touch

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, titanium

I working in Titanium Appcelerator Android Platform. I have seen sample created in alloy platform and openStreetMap.But i need to create in classic Titanium and in Google Maps V2,

Now i need to **draw some particular** locations in the map to get the location details. [image]

Is there any easy way to do it or any modules available . Please help.

Comment: why would you need to use Classic instead of alloy?

Comment: @ Rene Pot : yes i need to use in classic.

Comment: If all you have to do is to transfer from alloy to classic then you just recreate every single obj that is listed in the xml files directly in the js (classic) files. There are no modules for that, you need to rewrite part of the code. Please note that alloy is just a framework for easier development (using the MVC design pattern), that aside, the coding should be very similar.